# Drag and drop with wpf and nested listview

Tags: wpf, listview, drag-and-drop

I have a model like this:

```
<List>
<Obj Number="1">
    <Group Number="1">
        <Detail Name="AAA"/>
    </Group >
</Obj >
<Obj  Number="2">
    <Group Number="1">
        <Detail Name="BBB"/>
    </Group >
</Obj >
<Obj Number="3">
    <Group Number="1">
        <Detail Name="CCC"/>
    </Group >
    <Group Number="2">
        <Detail Name="DDD"/>
    </Group >
</Obj >
</Lista>
```

I want to be able to drag a Detail into another Group or into white space (in order to create parent elements Obj and Group)

I have created DataTemplate for each entity with a ListView inside Obj and Group entities template.
But every example I have found on web can't drag correctly the element because mouse events are raised from the parent ListView and not from the ListView that contains Details entities.